# Test report is not creating while running from XMLRunner

Tags: python, python-2.7, report, python-unittest

I am running Unit TestCases from Python Using XMLTestRunner.

This is my main file:

```
#LoggingService.py
class LoggerWriter:
    # used to redirect console msgs to the log
    def write(self, message):
        log_event('warning', 'Console', message)

def direct_console_to_log():
    global console_redirected
    # This function can be called several times. Avoid redirecting more than once
    if not console_redirected:
        console_output = LoggerWriter()
        sys.stderr = console_output
        sys.stdout = console_output
        console_redirected = True

def log_event(level, _id, event_details):
    # log the event
    pass
```

This is my one of the testing file:

```
#LoggingServiceTest.py
import unittest
import LoggingService
from LoggingService import direct_console_to_log
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('LoggingService.log_event')
    def test_log_writer(self,log_mock):
        direct_console_to_log()
        print ('console msg')
        self.assertTrue(log_mock.called)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I used to run all the test file from XMLRunner.py:

```
#XMLRunner.py
from xmlrunner import XMLTestRunner
import unittest

test_modules = [file1.Test, file2.Test, LoggingServiceTest.py, .... file25.Test]
suite = unittest.TestSuite()

for test_module in test_modules:
    tests = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(test_module)
    suite.addTests(tests)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # import xmlrunner
    # unittest.main(testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output='test-reports'))
    XMLTestRunner(output='test-reports').run(suite)
```

When I am trying to run LoggingServiceTest.py file from "XMLRunner.py", then the test report does not generate.But when I try without "LoggingServiceTest.py", then the report generates successfully.

And I am not sure, what is happening with the test case function
**(test_log_writer(self,log_mock)) in LoggingServiceTest.py** running.
Can anyone clear me

I use the following command to run the test case:

```
Python2.7.14\python.exe -m coverage run -p --branch --source=. --omit=Unit_Tests/*.py Unit_Tests/Testing.py
```

Comment: You say *more test files*, but how many more? Is the suite failing silently, or are you receiving an error? If the latter, please post it. Also, have a look at [How Do I Ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am not receiving any error, the test cases run successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution after debugging more.

When start test case from XMLRunner, It is creating some file objects for to write stderr and stdout and it is defined in `sys.stderr, sys.stdout` variable

And my test case is overwrite the `sys.stderr, sys.stdout` variable.

So XMLRunner try to fetching file objects from `sys.stderr, sys.stdout`, but it is not there, then it is not generating report.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your solution? As I do not get any report and I am not understanding how you solved it.